# Logging a variable set by nginx's Lua module

Tags: nginx, lua

I am trying to use the Lua module in nginx to set a variable ("foo") based on JSON in the body of a request. Then I want to log the value of that variable to the access log.

Like so:

```
http {
    log_format mylogfmt '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] \
        "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" \
        "$http_user_agent" "$foo"'
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://remote-server.example.com/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_connect_timeout 150;
    proxy_send_timeout 100;
    proxy_read_timeout 100;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    rewrite_by_lua '
        cjson = require "cjson"
        ngx.req.read_body()
        body_table = cjson.decode(ngx.var.request_body)
        ngx.var.foo = body_table["foo"]
    ';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log mylogfmt;
}
```

However, nginx won't start with this configuration. It complains thusly:

```
danslimmon@whatever:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] unknown "foo" variable
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I tried adding a 'set $foo "-"' to the location, but that just seems to override what I'm doing in Lua.

Thoughts?

[My nginx -V output](https://gist.github.com/danslimmon/9ed99c63aa6c04bd1a41/raw/e73bbdfb1c0ead08dd4df80b936dc233542df8bc/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: nginx is saying that you did not declare variable `foo`. You are right that you should set `$foo` before calling `rewrite_by_lua`. Why do you think it overrides what you do in Lua?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the variable $foo before the Lua module can use it.  Check [the doc for an example defining the variable within the location directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.var.VARIABLE) before utilizing it.

Comment: this is the problem of linking to a external resource as a answer... now that page do not exists anymore

Answer (score 0):

So as the link above do not work anymore, do this:

```
  server {
    (...)
    map $host $foo {
        default '';
    }
    (rest of your code)
  }
```

This because you can not use `set` inside the server block and this is the best way to define the variable to all the vhosts. `geoip` could also be a good option